# What is the three spaces after ' uniq -c ' command in shell

Tags: shell, uniq

When using shell (bash) in os x, I execute `uniq -c`, then output is added three spaces to each line. What is this spaces? How can I eliminate that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common `uniq` implementations add padding spaces on the left to align the counts number. This both looks neater and allows for correct sorting by count even with a "brutal" lexicographical sort; notice however that this courtesy doesn't seem to be mandated by POSIX.

You can easily trim them adding `sed` in pipe:

```
uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work! I understand why there is that padding ! I feel wonderful !